# Не могу получить список файлов и папок google

Tags: java, rest, retrofit2, google-drive

Пытаюсь получить список файлов и папок Google Drive. В документации написано для того, чтобы получить список нужно выполнить такой запрос:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я собственно и сделал:

```
 @GET("/drive/v2/files")
    Call<String> getListFiles(@Query("access_token") String access_token);
```

В результате получаю ошибку 403. В чем причина?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как вы отправляете, токен верный? вы разрешили доступ в google?

Comment: @danilshik здесь на 5 шаге я получил токен https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#callinganapi . доступ разрешил, иначе бы токен не смог бы получить

Comment: а где у вас headers?

Comment: предоставьте код отправки

Comment: @danilshik @GET("/drive/v3/files")
    Call<String> getListFiles(@Header("Authorization") String access_token); сделал вот так тоже не работает

Comment: @danilshik там ничего интересного

Comment: что в scope прописано?